# How to install Cordova correctly?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, kubuntu

I am installing Cordova from official [resource](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/) but cannot install it. I have run into the following problem. I have seen same questions on the site but they didn't offer a solution that worked.. Here is output from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cordova-cli
```

Thank you for any help
after command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
```

I have:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 607, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/zesty
```

Comment: Did you issue the command `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa` followed by the command `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read different resource and found decision which works for me:

Install Cordova in these steps with dependencies:
**Installing Node.js.**
Node.js may already be installed. To test the installation, open a terminal window and type:

```
nodejs --version
```

If the version number is displayed, Node.js is installed.
If Node.js is not installed, install with:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Also add the alias "`node`" for nodejs, as this is needed by Cordova:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

**Install Node Package Manager (npm)**. Test if `npm` is installed by typing:

```
npm --version
```

If `npm` is not installed, install with:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

**Installing Git**.
Git is a version control system, which is used by Cordova behind-the-scenes. Test if Git is installed by typing:

```
git --version
```

If Git is not installed, install with:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

**Installing Cordova**. Cordova is installed using the Node Package Manager (npm). Type the following to install:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

My test the Cordova install by typing:

```
$ cordova --version
7.0.1
```

If you see the version number, you have successfully installed Apache Cordova!

that leaves the issue with requirements ...
you don't have java jdk installed !
other requirements also not installed that ends with no usage of cordova .. :(

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.